# In Polymer 2.0 how to observe edits to properties of an object bound to an element inside dom-repeat?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

(This question and code sample is for Polymer 2, but it's possible the same issue is present in 1.x)

**The Goal:**

I want to create an element (the Editor) that allows viewing/editing of the properties of certain types of objects, and another element (the List) that displays editable arrays of these objects, delegating the viewing/editing to the Editor element, while retaining control over the addition/removal of obejcts from the list.  A to-do list is a good example of this (note: the Polymer to-do list examples floating around out there, as far as I'm aware, do not do what I need, read on to see why).  I am trying to do this in Polymer 2.0, but it's not clear that the issue is specific to 2.0.

**The Obstacle:**

First, here's a bit of code on plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Yji9kl63sOdnHJiv4CCU

The List element:

```
<link rel="import" href="./editor-element.html">

<dom-module id="list-element">
    <template>
        <dom-repeat items="{{list}}" as="item">
            <template>
                <div class="item">
                    <editor-element todo="{{item}}">
                    </editor-element>
                </div>
            </template>
        </dom-repeat>

    </template>
    <script>

        class ListElement extends Polymer.Element {

            static get is() {
                return "list-element";
            }

            static get properties() {
                return {
                    list: {
                        type: Array,
                        value:function() {
                            return []
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            ready() {
                super.ready();
                this.push("list", {
                    description:"one"
                })
                this.push("list", {
                    description:"two"
                })
                setTimeout(function() {
                    this.set("list.0.description", "one edited");
                }.bind(this), 500)
                setTimeout(function() {
                    this.push("list", {
                        description:"three"
                    })
                }.bind(this), 1000)
            }
        }

        customElements.define(ListElement.is, ListElement);

    </script>
</dom-module>
```

The Editor element:

```
<dom-module id="editor-element">
    <template>
        <div>Editor for [[todo.description]]</div>
    </template>
    <script>

        class EditorElement extends Polymer.Element {

            static get is() {
                return "editor-element";
            }

            static get properties() {
                return {
                    todo:{
                        type:Object,
                        value:function() {
                            return {};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            static get observers() {
                return [
                    "observe(todo.description)"
                ]
            }

            observe(p1) {
                console.log("Observed change for TODO item description: "+p1);
            }
        }

        customElements.define(EditorElement.is, EditorElement);

    </script>
</dom-module>
```

The problem is that the observer in the Editor that is supposed to watch for edits to a to-do item is being fired when a new to-do item is created, in addition to when an existing to-do item is edited.  This is happening BOTH for the new to-do item and for existing to-do items that have not been edited.  In other words, if I have item A and B already on the list, and I add item C, the to-do property observer in the Editor is fired three times, one for each new/existing item.  This happens regardless of whether the new item is pushed or unshifted onto/into the list.  I understand from discussion on the Polymer 2 slack channel that the unshift behaviour is to be expected, but the push behaviour is unexpected.

**The Question:**

What is the Polymer Way (2.0 preferably) to achieve this use case?  I do not want to pollute the List element with code to handle edits to a to-do item.  The to-do items themselves are objects that may gain more properties in the future, so I don't want to individually bind each property of the dom-repeated item to a property in the Editor element, because this is a code maintenance nuisance.  I want to just bind the entire to-do item in each pass of dom-repeat, and allow the Editor to deal with which properties are editable and how.

The answer to my question may be "Polymer can't do this" or it may be "You are misunderstanding something fundamental about Polymer", either or both of which I would love to know, so please set me straight if I am missing something important. Hopefully though, there is a polymer way to do what I'm asking.

Comment: Are you referring to something distinct from dom-repeat?  I am looping, but the template stamped out in each loop is handled by the editor element.  Is there another way to do this what would avoid the issues I mentioned but retain the separation between the list of items vs the items themselves?

Comment: Just to double check: I've ported your `polymer+:2.0-preview` snippet to [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryerpE?editors=1011) with a push button, as per @tony19 solution, and an edit button: is this what you see in the console? it seems to me that only new items or edited ones are fired...

Comment: @user1892538 it's true that with 2.0-preview tony19's example works in the push scenario.  But in the unshift scenario (or I presume any scenario where array indices of elements change) the example works in 1.x but not in 2.0-preview.  I think this is the trickier part, since it prevents me from achieving the goals laid out in the general case of a mutable list bound to a parent element, where the items are modified via a child element.

Comment: oh.. the `unshift` fires all the items, while `push` and `edit` fire a single item: we're on the same page, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observer usage in 2.0 seems correct already, and I think you might be seeing a bug in the `2.0-preview` branch. I recommend creating a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues) for this, so that the Polymer team could confirm/clarify.

FWIW, the issue does not occur in Polymer 1.x (i.e., the observer is only invoked for the newly added item), as seen in this [demo](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/wJGqxV?editors=1011):

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  class EditorElement {
    beforeRegister() {
      this.is = 'editor-element';
      this.properties = {todo: Object};
      this.observers = ["observe(todo.description)"];
    }

    observe(p1) {
      console.log("Observed change for TODO item description: "+p1);
    }
  }
  Polymer(EditorElement);

  class ListElement {
    beforeRegister() {
      this.is = 'list-element';

      this.properties = {
        list: {
          type: Array,
          value: () => []
        }
      };
    }

    _pushItem() {
      this.push("list", {description: `item ${this.list.length}`});
    }
  }
  Polymer(ListElement);
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.8.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <list-element></list-element>

  <dom-module id="editor-element">
    <template>
      <div>Editor for [[todo.description]]</div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  
  <dom-module id="list-element">
    <template>
      <button on-click="_pushItem">Push item</button>

      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{list}}">
        <div class="item">
          <editor-element todo="{{item}}">
          </editor-element>
        </div>
      </template>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

</body>
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer assuming I confirm that this is a bug in the preview branch. If it turns out it's the expected behaviour instead, we'll go back to the drawing board.  As a side note, if you take tony19's demo code and change push to unshift, the observers are **still** fired as expected (once for each new item unshifted).  So it definitely does seem like a change in behaviour from 1.x to 2.0-preview so far.