# How to distinguish between structural changes to array made in parent element vs property changes to an item of array made in child element observer?

Tags: polymer

This appears to be similar to a question I asked earlier: [In Polymer 2.0 how to observe edits to properties of an object bound to an element inside dom-repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561573/in-polymer-2-0-how-to-observe-edits-to-properties-of-an-object-bound-to-an-eleme)

But it's not.  The code example is similar, but the question is focusing on a different aspect of that code.

Here is the example code: https://plnkr.co/edit/iTZqM4GwpASEqQgtRGEk

The list element:

```
<link rel="import" href="./editor-element.html">

<dom-module id="list-element">
    <template>
        <dom-repeat items="{{list}}" as="item">
            <template>
                <div class="item">
                    <editor-element description="{{item.description}}">
                    </editor-element>
                </div>
            </template>
        </dom-repeat>

    </template>
    <script>

        class ListElement extends Polymer.Element {

            static get is() {
                return "list-element";
            }

            static get properties() {
                return {
                    list: {
                        type: Array,
                        value:function() {
                            return []
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            ready() {
                super.ready();
                this.push("list", {
                    description:"one"
                })
                this.push("list", {
                    description:"two"
                })
                setTimeout(function() {
                    this.set("list.0.description", "one edited");
                }.bind(this), 500)
                setTimeout(function() {
                    this.unshift("list", {
                        description:"three"
                    })
                }.bind(this), 1000)
            }
        }

        customElements.define(ListElement.is, ListElement);

    </script>
</dom-module>
```

And the editor element:

```
<dom-module id="editor-element">
    <template>
        <div>Editor for [[description]]</div>
    </template>
    <script>

        class EditorElement extends Polymer.Element {

            static get is() {
                return "editor-element";
            }

            static get properties() {
                return {
                    description:String
                }
            }

            static get observers() {
                return [
                    "observe(description)"
                ]
            }

            observe(description) {
                console.log("Observed change for TODO item: "+description);
            }
        }

        customElements.define(EditorElement.is, EditorElement);

    </script>
</dom-module>
```

In the list (parent) element, two todo items are pushed onto the array, the first one is modified, and then a third item is unshifted into the array.

The observer in the editor (child) element is triggered twice for the pushes, and once for the edit.  So far so good.  It's then triggered three times for the unshift.

I understand the logic behind this, the unshift scrambles the mapping between data and elements, which are re-used to render the newly assigned data.

**My question is this:**

How do I write an observer that can distinguish between observations triggered by a restructuring of the array, vs those triggered by an edit to a property of an item in that array?

Unshift is enough to illustrate this, but the same thing would happen if the dom-repeat has a sort or filter applied.

Just to clarify, I'm neither here nor there on the fact that the addition of **one** item to the array in the parent element results in an observable change in **every** dom-repeated child element.  What is important however is that I can distinguish that observable change from the mutation of a property in one specific child element.  In the approach shown in the sample code, I cannot, so it might mean I have taken the wrong approach to data binding here.